# Селектор не отображает выбранное значение

Tags: html, jsp

Селекторный список не отображает выбранное в нем значение. В базу данных необходимое числовое значение добавляется, но именно в селекторе всегда остается текстовое значение под номером 1. Как изменить код, чтобы в селекторе отображалось выбранное значение из бд?

```
<td>Choose one program:</td>
        <td><select class="mt-2 p-1 form-select" name="admission" id="admission">
  <option value="1">Psychology</option>
  <option value="2">Tourism</option>
  <option value="3">International Business</option>
  <option value="4">Management of Sustainable Tourism Development (Master)</option>
  <option value="5">Clinical Psychology (Master)</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<option value="3" selected>International Business</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Записываешь отправленные данные в переменную

```
$adm = $_COOKIE['admission'] ; 
или $adm = $_SESSION['admission'] ;
или $adm = $_GET['admission'] ;
```

проверяешь:

```
<option value="1" <?= !$adm?' selected':'' ?>>Psychology</option>
```